# No operator matches these operands adding student objects to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to make an add function that will add student objects directly to an array attribute which sadly has to be an array of pointers so that I can later print every single attribute of the student objects out of the roster.

```
void Roster::add(string studentID, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, int age, int daysInCourse1, int daysInCourse2, int daysInCourse3, DegreeProgram degreeprogram) {
        int daysInCourse[3] = { daysInCourse1,daysInCourse2,daysInCourse3 };
        student item10;
        //Create an array of 5 pointers, which point to objects of type student
        //Assigns a new student to each index
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this->classRosterArray[i] = new student();
        }

        //Sets attributes for each item
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            this->classRosterArray[i].setStudentID(studentID);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setfirstName(firstName);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setLastName(lastName);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setEmailAddress(emailAddress);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setAge(age);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setNumOfDays(daysInCourse);
            this->classRosterArray[i].setPrograme(degreeprogram);
        }
}
```

Comment: This isn't all your code, and you didn't say what's wrong or about what you have a question.  Not sure what you want.  However, it will leak when you assign 5 new students into classRosterArray each time add is called.  What happens to the old 5 students?  Why do you only set fields on the first 3 of them?

Comment: Why does adding *one* student first reallocate the array, throwing away what you already had, and then store three identical students in the array?

Comment: I'm uncertain as I come from a python and basic C# background.

Comment: @Secret_Name "In order to add a student to the roster, first create five new `student` objects and then set the data of the first three to the same things" is very odd in those languages as well.

Comment: I haven't slept in about 30 hours. Lol, I did not notice that I was doing that. Thank you for pointing that out.